# Missed Expected OG, Sparging Issue?

Tags: all-grain, original-gravity, efficiency, sparge

I brewed my first all grain batch this past weekend and everything went pretty smooth except my OG was 1.050 instead of the 1.056 I was expecting.

Would this be a sparging issue? I had calculated a 75% efficiency. I did fly sparging with a home made sparge arm that worked pretty well. I had to adjust the flow a couple times to maintain a flow that ended in 45 minutes with close to 7 gallons collected for a 5 gallon batch.

I boiled off between 1.25 and 1.5 gallons of wort.

If this isn't a sparge efficiency issue what else could it be?

Comment: Could be because 7 minus 1.5 boil off isn't 5 gallons.  5.5 gallons of 1.050 wort would equate to 5gal of 1.055 wort if boiled to the 5 gal target.  If the recipe was formulated for 5 gallons and not 5.5 or 5.75 gallons... that's the issue.

Comment: @brewchez This is what I was looking for, that is exactly what happened. The recipe did target 5 gallons. Thanks!